# Ignore enter key when inputting char

Tags: c++, validation

I'm trying to validate a simple input of a char, but if the user presses enter without typing in a char, it simply prints a blank line in the console until characters are entered. I'd like to accept the enter key as an invalid input and proceed to my validation rather than just go to an empty line.

```
cout << "Enter room type. (S)tandard or (P)remium: ";
char roomType;
cin >> roomType;
while (cin.fail() || roomType != 's' && roomType != 'S' && roomType != 'p' && roomType != 'P')
{
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(80, '\n');
    cout << "Error. Enter room type again: ";
    cin >> roomType;
}
cin.ignore(80, '\n');
cin.clear();
return roomType;
```

Comment: I've updated my answer below @KeeganHeffernan. Please check it to see whether it works for you (it works just fine for me).

Answer (score 0):

***** Edited my answer again

I found the solution as to why it's not outputting an error message for entering a newline character. Apparently, this line:

```
    cin.ignore(80, '\n');
```

Is the root of the problem. On one hand, your condition in the while loop says that you are supposed to treat the newline character as a violation and print a error message. However, on the other hand, the above line tells the compiler to ignore the newline character without even checking whether it violates the condition of the while loop or not. You will have to remove this line so that the compiler will even accept the newline character for checking whether it violates the condition, or for any other purpose. I've updated the code below:

```
    // Example program
    #include <iostream>
    #include <conio.h>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        cout << "Enter room type. (S)tandard or (P)remium: ";
        char roomType;
        roomType = _getch();
        while (cin.fail() || (roomType != 's' && roomType != 'S' && roomType != 'p' && roomType != 'P') || (roomType == '\n'))
        {
            //cin.clear();
            cout << "\nError. Enter room type again: ";
            roomType = _getch();
            cout << roomType;
        }
        //cin.clear();
        cout << "\n\nSuccess" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

By the way, I also commented out the cin.clear() function because while it was not making much of a difference in the code, I was not sure whether you were required to have that line in the code or not. I still stuck to the _getch() function as the cin could not catch the newline character (I tried it using cin and _getch(), only the latter worked)

In case you wanted to know the difference, the _getch() is termed as a keylogger, simply because rather than waiting for the user to hit the newline button, it logs every single key the user hits on the keyboard, and it stores it in the variable. As a result, it was able to catch the newline character in the code above. It is a part of the  file. If you want any more information regarding the _getch() function, visit this site:

[_getch, _getche](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa297934(v=vs.60).aspx)

This should work for you now. If it still doesn't work for you, just inform me in the comments box.

Comment: Why just slap a `10` when you can use the much more understandable `'\n'`? It will spare you the explanations.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. wouldn't it be roomtype == 10 though? because having it equal that is the case that would trigger the validation?

EDIT: tested both and the console still outputs blank lines instead of an error message.

Comment: You're right, @KeeganHeffernan, that's what came to my mind when I posted my first solution. However, they both mean the same thing as 10 is the ascii value for '\n' in the ascii table. So they can be used interchangeably in this case.

Comment: @NewbietoProgramming I've tried both solutions and i still end up with blank lines.

Comment: If you hit the enter button twice, it outputs the invalid message and proceeds to ask for the input again, @KeeganHeffernan. Also, have you tried it with the code I updated above?

Comment: *"Both methods are correct."* - No, they are not. They happen to work, on your machine, given your compiler and OS. That is coincidental, not contractual. C++ doesn't mandate ASCII encoding (or any character encoding), `\n` could map to **anything**. `\n` is correct. `10` sometimes isn't.